# Cs50 Mario: How can I improve this code?

Tags: c, cs50

It took me all day to figure this out but even though I completed it I don't fully understand how it works and I feel there is a better or cleaner way of writing it.

Can some one explain how I can improve my code?

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rows, height, spaces, hashes;

    do
    {
        printf("Height: ");
        height = get_int();
    }
    while(height < 0 || height > 23);

    for(rows = 0 ; rows < height; rows++)
    {
        for(spaces = height - 1; spaces > rows; spaces--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(hashes = 0; hashes < spaces + 2; hashes++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `putchar('#')` etc to output single characters instead of using `printf("#")` etc.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could change `spaces` and `hashes` to loop-scoped variables, with: `for(int spaces = height - 1; spaces > rows; spaces--) {}` and `for(int hashes = 0; hashes < rows + 2; hashes++) {}`.

Comment: I did not know about putchar(), I barely stated learning C last night and used what I learned from the lecture.

Comment: The code's not bad... and you've already got some suggested minor improvements.  I'd be more concerned about the "I don't fully understand how it works" part than about the code you have.

Comment: Then I would say that you are doing well. Note that in my above comment I used `hashes < rows + 2` instead of `hashes < spaces + 2`, since at this point in the posted code, `spaces == rows` is always true; also, loop-scoped means that in my version, `spaces` only exists inside the `for` loop where it is declared. IAC, critiquing working code and suggesting improvements is exactly what is done over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can use code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to request suggestion about your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is best if you first try to understand what the code is doing. Work it through on paper, starting with the input `1`.

If you are keen you might like to explore the `printf` [width and precision formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx), where each `*` in the format specifier is replaced by the corresponding function argument. But beware - `printf` is a complicated and detailed function. This also introduces the **array**.

```
char hatch[] = "##############################";
for(rows = 0; rows < height; rows++) {
    printf("%*.*s\n", height + 1, rows + 2, hatch);
}
```

For the input of `1` your program prints

```
##
```

For the input of `5` it prints

```
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

and so does this. The loop contains a single instruction.